# Can't create a link to a page in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to create a single link (inside a snippit) that will link to any given page but I can't figure out how to do it. I am using this general structure:

```
{{ 'Link Text' | link_to: X }}
```

I don't know what the parameter for x should be to access page/product on my site. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you explain a but more what you are trying to do exactly, and why a simple `<a href="...">` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From: `wiki.shopify.com/Link_to` (link now broken)

```
{{ 'Typo' | link_to: 'http://typo.leetsoft.com' }}
```

This should create a link that looks like:

```
<a href="http://typo.leetsoft.com">Typo</a>
```

More info on links in liquid here:  http://wiki.shopify.com/Link

**Update 1:**
You should also be able to use relative links:

```
{{ 'Typo' | link_to: 'pages/home' }} <!-- relative to current page -->
{{ 'Typo' | link_to: '/pages/home' }} <!-- relative to site root -->
{{ 'Typo' | link_to: '../pages/home' }} <!-- relative to parent dir -->
```

**Update 2:**
Ore better yet, you can reference the page's handle: **{{ 'Title' | pages.pagehandle.url }}**

- http://wiki.shopify.com/Pages
- http://wiki.shopify.com/Page

Comment: right - but this isn't what I want. I want to create a relative link to an internal page. Do I have to hardcode the link each time? That wouldn't maintain very good flexibility. So, if I want to create a link from the body pages/home and point it to pages/products (not collections - simply an actual page) - how would I do that?

Comment: Still not 100% that I understand what you're looking for.  Does the edit to my question help?

Comment: Yes, that works - but I guess I was hoping for something closer to a:

    {{ 'Typo' | link_to: page.handle.home }}

so that if I needed to later change any data from the page, it would get updated automatically.

Comment: Yea, I'm sorry.  IDK if its possible or not - can't find anything in the DOCS...  Sounds like this approach would be fine unless your URL structure changes though, right?

Comment: Ok, after poking around a bit more... Does this work? `{{ 'Title' | pages.pagehandle.url` }}

Comment: I wasn't using the .url parameter - I'm guessing this is something to the effect of class.filter.object? Either way - that works great! And SHOULD be in the docs. :) Thanks for the help.